# Are mini batches sampled randomly in Keras' Sequential.fit method()

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, gradient-descent

When you `.fit` a Keras `Sequential()` model, you can specify a `batch_size` parameter. I have noteiced it is sometimes defined independently from the actual dataset size. Does it mean that mini-batches are sampled randomly, instead of scrolling down the dataset from top to bottom, slice by slice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `shuffle=True` as an argument of the `model.fit` method, Keras will shuffle the dataset before splitting it into batches ([source](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)), otherwise the dataset will be processed sequentially.

Comment: If you set a number of epochs and a batch size so that the number of observations are note enough... is the algorithm repeating from the start?

Comment: what do you mean by "the number of observations are not enough"? if you have small batch size, you update the weights more frequently and vice versa. if you have more epochs, you go over the complete dataset more times.

Comment: Let's say you have 1000 observations. If you set batch size = 100 and epochs = 20... does it start back from the top?

Comment: it will restart 20 times from the top, because you have 20 epochs. And during each one of the 20 iterations, it will re-segment the data into batches of size 100.

Comment: And when it restarts, does it make any reshuffle of the dataset, or always the same sequence of batches is fed into the Network?

Comment: good question, I am not sure about that but I would also like to know :)

Answer (score 2):

[**The relevant documentation**](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) doesn't mention random sampling per se.

NOTE: this all has nothing to do with the `Sequential` model type versus the `Model` type. OP was specifically talking about `Sequential` models.

You can specify the `shuffle` parameter to get random samples across the training dataset, but there is not a strict/parameterised sampling methodology. Using `shuffle=True` is however equiavalent to random selection without replacement (smaples can only be sampled once per epoch).

You can look through [**the source code**](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py) to see how Keras builds up the train function, but it doesn't include any random sampling. This is taken care of deeper in the internals, via e.g. the `fit_loop` function, which simply [**shuffles the indices**](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L180) of the training samples:

```
if shuffle == 'batch':
    index_array = batch_shuffle(index_array, batch_size)
elif shuffle:
    np.random.shuffle(index_array)
```

---

You could pass `class_weight` argument to tell the Keras that some samples should be considered more important when computing the loss (although it doesn't affect the sampling method itself):

> **class_weight**: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to
>   a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during
>   training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more
>   attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

Comment: The class_weight affects the loss function, not the sampling probablity

Comment: you mention "You can specify the shuffle parameter to **get random samples** across the training dataset." and then "see how Keras builds up the train function, but it **doesn't include any random sampling**", I think that's adversarial.

Comment: I have updated to address comments - @pcko1 - I hope that is clearer now?

Comment: Thanks for updating it but I think the message is still a bit confusing. You mention that random sampling is different than random shuffling, but in reality `random.shuffle` is equivalent to `random.choice(replace=False)`, which samples numbers randomly. Long story short, `np.random.shuffle` **will randomly** shuffle your dataset.

Comment: Good point - I just wanted to specoify that not smapling methods are really used, just shuffling the indices, but it is not parameterisable. I'll make another edit  :)